# Alcohol sales dropping due to name similarity with other things

Tags: history, health, drink

**Corona beer sales are dropping due to the coronavirus-19 because of a possible similarity in name?**

Are there any other know sales of some wine, beer or other alcoholic drinks that have plummeted due to such naming similarities  in the present pandemic or some other historically known pandemic, even at a local level?

> As of February 2020, after the COVID-19 coronavirus spread throughout China, Corona suffered a $170 million loss in earnings in the country. The company attributed the sales drop to fewer people going out in public, with many bars and restaurants being forced to close down. Multiple brands of beer experienced relative sales slumps in the country, as the spread of the COVID-19 coronavirus had generally dampened public activities. Sales were typically high over the period, due to Chinese New Year celebrations. - [Corona (beer)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_(beer))

Although Corona beer sales have dropped, it is not unique at the moment, the sale other drinks and beer sales have dropped. I am only interested in historical name tagging of some sort of alcoholic drinks that are associated with some sort of historical flue or pandemic?

If one can find the opposite frenzy that occurred in the above situations that would be acceptable data for an answer too.

Here follows a satire on the Corona beer demise:

[image: Mexican beer rebrands as Ebola to avoid association with coronavirus]

[**Mexican beer rebrands as Ebola to avoid association with coronavirus**](https://www.the-postillon.com/2020/01/Corona-Ebola.html)

> Mexico City (dpo) - The dangerous coronavirus is spreading quickly and is a source of fear for many. In order to avoid associations with the negative headlines, Mexican commercial brewery Grupo Modelo has announced that its most popular beer, Corona Extra, is to be rebranded as Ebola Extra. “We don’t want our customers to feel like they are drinking an infectious disease,” explained a spokesperson for Grupo Modelo, hence the decision to go for a worldwide rebrand.
>
> The new name, Ebola, is a neologism with a lovely ring to it according to the brewery. It stands for Extremo abocado liquido con ácido ascórbico or “very quaffable liquid containing ascorbic acid.” Ascorbic acid is an ingredient of Corona (now Ebola) along with water, hops, yeast, barley malt, maize, rice and papain.
>
> The rebrand will be part of a multimedia ad campaign featuring the catchy slogan, “I’m doing great. I’ve got Ebola.

Comment: I’m guessing, but I think the linked site is satire.

Comment: I'm not guessing, the linked site is satire.  Corona hasn't seen a drop in sales due to the virus.  [Snopes link](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/corona-beer-fear-coronavirus/).  The question is an interesting one though, and I'm guessing there are some very interesting and historically accurate answers to be had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of at least one rebranding due to an unfortunate naming convention - though it has nothing to do with a pandemic: **Vergina Beer**

[image: Vergina Beer]

[**Rebranding Vergina**](https://www.packagingoftheworld.com/2020/08/rebranding-vergina.html)

From a greek brewing company... they have since simply rebranded by going back to the greek spelling:

[image: Greek Spelling]

That is not to say that there aren't others... furthermore, there are plenty of companies that should consider rebranding, if they have not already... For example:

**Sh*t Wine** (literal translation)

[image: Shit Wine]

**A couple others:**

[image: unfortunate name1]

[image: unfortunate name2]

An image search for "worst alcohol brand names" turns up some fairly hilarious results  :)

Comment: To be honest, though - I would imagine that a clever, funny, or even obscene name might help rather than hinder sales of an alcoholic beverage

Comment: The image in the Beaver logo (and the "Me So Hor̶ney" is likely deliberate: [Belching Beaver’s change of art | San Diego Reader]Preview Copy Tweet
(https://www.sandiegoreader.com/news/2017/mar/14/stringers-belching-beavers-change-art/)

Comment: I imagine so, as well... the name and logo of the company isn't the most... erm... feminist. But perhaps being in poor taste actually works for their sales?